# Colons in html tags <h:section>...</h:section>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Has anyone ever seen this before? I'm looking at a site that does this at the moment.

http://www.web.de/

document.querySelectorAll and JQuery have trouble parsing the tags as selectors...

Any help or advice gratefully received...

Comment: Those are colons, not semi-colors and they aren't in HTML.

Comment: And yes I thought they weren't valid html either.